# charging lead acid cells

Tags: batteries, lead-acid

And I have forklift battery 24V which is almost at the end of life. The 24V charger is very strong and heat battery and not working properly. 
I have one 12V battery charger, which works very fine.
24v Lead acid battery has 12 cells in series. And I can read 12V on first 6 cells. It is safe to charge this first 6 cells and after then rest six cells with 12V charger?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can charge half the battery and later charge the other half.  But a better alternative might be to look for a method to reduce the charge rate of the 24V charger.  putting a resistor in series with its output could be one way to do that.  Perhaps a coil of steel wire.